# APK Expansion files on the Kindle Fire

Tags: android, kindle, kindle-fire

Is it possible to use the [Android Expansion files](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/expansion-files.html) with a Kindle Fire?
Because the Kindle Fire doesn't use Google Play.

EDIT: Amazon allows the .apk to get bigger than 50MB, so no expansion files are needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since expansion files are downloaded from the Google Play Store, I guess the answer is sadly no.

Answer (score 2):

What about just turn on "Allow Installation of Application From Unknown Sources" (Settings => Device) and then simple install .apk via any file manager?

Comment: Sure. But the question was about possibility itself.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a zip, so sure. What's missing is the downloading. So you can add the obb as an asset in your fire release flavour and change the code that gets the `ZipResourceFile` to load zip from there.

For faster development in a fire debug flavour, you can always manually copy the file to the normal `/andoird/obb` location on the fire